# Internal vs External tab sizes in files with Atom

Tags: file, indentation, atom-editor

I work at a Linux software company that has a simple requirement that any tabs in stored source code (ie, in our source repository) should indicate an indent to the next multiple-of-8 column.

Whether we indent our code by 2 spaces, 4, or 8 is generally up to us. Users of VI or emacs have no trouble with this, but we have an issue where many programmers use IDEs that convert hard tabs to multiples of spaces, and when saving back the files now have completely jumbled indentation.

Looking around, Atom seems like a good IDE to transition folks to, as most have not expressed any particular preference in which IDE they use. However, I have not been able to figure out how to configure it so that tabs are always stored as traditional hard tabs (indent to next multiple of 8) while internally the tab key performs whatever indentation the user has set their style to.

Is is possible to set up Atom to do what we want, and if not, is there some IDE that can? I mean, if ancient editors like emacs and vi can handle it, why not a modern IDE????

Let me rephrase the above, for added clarity.

1) On saving and on loading, tabs indicate an indent to the next mod 8 column and the editor displays the loaded text accordingly.

2) When editing, hitting the tab key inserts spaces and/or hard tabs to the next logical indent spacing, which can be 2, 4, 8, or whatever the user wants. (ie, if the next indent-by-2 would be to a column mod 8, using a hard return for this is perfectly acceptable, but not required)

Comment: I think you're out of luck. I don't believe I've ever seen this capability outside of Vim. You may also find that this practice confuses new hires. My personal advice to your company is to re-evaluate the practice, if that's a feasible option.

Comment: There are only really two options for file formats that work when people have different ideas about indents: The first is to forbid tabs in output source files, and the second is to have everyone agree on a standard interpretation. Having an editor that accommodates this seems a perfectly reasonable requirement to me.

Comment: Let me re-state what I was saying - I'm not saying your practice is itself bad or you should not use it. You should, as a company, do what works for you. I am merely suggesting that the way modern tools work may make that more difficult for you, and that the existing habits of new hires may make this practice confusing for them. YMMV...